# React JS: Показать сообщение об успешной отправке по API

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть компонент, в котором я по API отправляю запрос. Если запрос успешно отправлен, то я делаю редирект в другой компонент. Мне нужно перед редиректом показать сообщение об успешной отправке.

Я думал о том, чтобы передавать ключ msg в строке запроса, и затем в зависимости от него показывать сообщение в следующем компоненте.

Ещё я думал о том, чтобы перед редиректом в течение двух секунд показывать сообщение "Успешно" и после истечения времени делать редирект, но мне это не походит.

```
this.props.router.navigate(`/product-detail/?id=${response.data.id}&msg=true`);
```

Comment: А где вопрос-то?